# Run TestComplete UI Tests from TFS 2018

Tags: visual-studio, ui-testing, testcomplete, gui-testing

I created some UI tests with both TestLeft and TestComplete from SmartBear, using integration into VS to run them as VS test items.

With TFS2015, I did install a VSO agent on a physical server, which started in interactive mode (not as a service) on reboot. My build contained the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" step followed by a "Run Functional Tests" step.

With TFS2018, it's a slightly different VSTS agent, and I want to use the "Visual Studio Test" step. Everything is fine and the tests run as long as I have open desktop connection to the server.
However if I reboot the server, and the agent starts on reboot, my tests fail with "Unable to initialize TestComplete" due to the need for an interactive workstation.

So I just can't find a way to run the tests from TFS2018 the way they ran from TFS2015.

Edit: I already tried starting a batch file as Administrator containing
`%windir%\System32\tscon.exe XY /dest:console`
XY being the ID of my current Remote Desktop session, as suggested at https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html
When I run the tests from VS and than execute this batch file, the tests continue and UI objects are available.
However the build steps fails with the same message.

Thanks in advance,
Florian